# C++ Composition - must I wrap all those functions?

Tags: c++, oop, inheritance, composition

I've got a C++ class that describes an object's orientation in 3D space - location, rotation, scale, etc. I have other classes that necessarily need information like that (or a subset of it) - models, terrains, cameras, etc. Now I *could* make those subclasses of my orientation class, but the Googles have told me to prefer composition over inheritance. This philosophically makes sense - a model *is* not an orientation, it *has* one (and yes I know the is-a has-a thing is just a heuristic). Yet it seems needlessly, almost comically inelegant to rewrite the same wrapper methods for all those would-be subclasses just go get at that functionality. Things like `model.getOrientation().set_x(1)` seem silly as well.

I can see why this wouldn't be "too bad" for small objects, but for this example (and others like it), **what's the point of composition if you have to go through hoops anyway to pretend that you're using inheritance?** Should I even use it now? I'm almost certain I'm thinking about this improperly.

Comment: What's wrong with `model.orientation.set_x(1)`?

Comment: @Lol4t0 It seems verbose. Plus, shouldn't you just be able to tell an object to do something without dismantling it, so to speak? Maybe a similar design pattern instance would help?

Comment: The thing is that setting the orientation is not a telling object what to do (if object is not orientation). That! is actually a problem. You shouldn't set orientation for object, instead you should talk to them in their terms, like `monster->attack()` or `camera->zoom()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It may seem silly but your `model.getOrientation().set_x(1)` is probably the way to go.

If you get tired of typing the `getOrientation()` part, you could try something like this:

```
Orientation & orient = model.getOrientation();
orient.set_x(1);
orient.set_y(1);
if( orient.check_something() ) {
  //whatever
}
//etc.
```

Comment: I'm leaning towards this. Other people seem to agree with your answer. Can you expand on why this is the best/preferred way to do it?

Comment: 1. Little or no boilerplate 2. Maintains correct is-a/has-a relationships. 3. Is idiomatic: won't confuse other programmers

Answer (score 9):

There's a cheap way to avoid most of the wrapping boilerplate.

```
class model : private orientation {
  public:
    using orientation::set_x;
    ... etc ...
};
```

Private inheritance in C++ doesn't (necessarily) mean "is a". It's more-or-less invisible to outsiders, and is sometimes described as meaning "is implemented in terms of a". That is, you get a limited form of composition that helpfully gives you the ability to expose part or all of the interface of the composed object.

Answer (score 3):

Write a class for things that have an orientation. Let models, terrains, cameras etc. inherit from that class. If you want to do any wrapping, you need to do it in one class only. Using getters is done so that you can change the way the the orientation is stored in the object.

Comment: How is that different than just extending the orientation class?

Comment: It expresses the ideas more clearly. As you said, a model is not an orientation.

Comment: I like this idea. You don't get coupled to everything the `orientation` class has by inheriting from it, you can properly encapsulate whatever you need from the `orientation` class, and then re-use those encapsulated properties/methods by inheriting from this intermediate class (given that models, terrains, cameras all use the same subset of features from an `orientation` object)

Comment: I personally think that it is just cheating. When you do such thing, patterns wagging you. (I mean, in case you wrap the whole interface of orientation, not only `Orientation& orientation()` function)